# Jquery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'css' of undefined

Tags: jquery

Good day.

When i use code:

```
$(this).children('.test')[0].css('display','none');
```

i get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'css' of undefined`

Why i get it error an how write aright?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to use [eq(0)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) since `[0]` returns plain DOM element and it does not have `css` method on it.

```
$(this).children('.test').eq(0).css('display','none'); //or .hide()
```

or

```
$(this).children('.test:eq(0)').css('display','none');//or .hide()
```

or

```
$(this).children('.test')[0].style.display = 'none';
```

Also you error means that it could any `.test` which are children of the context [You are accessing css method on undefined since your selector did not return anything]. Note that children will only look for the direct descendants, if you want to look deep you can use `find`. If your selection had passed and returned the element then your code would have returned `[element] has no method css`. The above snippets (first 2) using jquery will suppress these errors.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
$(this).children('.test').eq(0).hide()
```